# from pysnmp.hlapi import * ImportError: No module named hlapi

Tags: pysnmp

I install the package and it dependencies module in ubuntu 15.10 but still it show error of

from pysnmp.hlapi import *
ImportError: No module named hlapi

I try to install it
sudo setup.py install
and 
pip install pysnmp

But still its not working

Please help me to get it complete

Comment: You need pysnmp 4.3.x to use the latest API (which is pysnmp.hlapi). How about: pip install -U pysnmp ?

Comment: I run this cmd also but facing the same problem

Comment: That means you are still running older version of pysnmp. Could you figure out where your Python finds pysnmp package (python -v -c 'import pysnmp' 2>&1 | grep pysnmp) and upgrade that package or point Python to other location where pysnmp 4.3 resides?

Comment: I have the same problem using Python with Windows 10. I have pysnmp4.3.2 installed. I installed it with pip

Answer (score 2):

```
apt-get install python-pip
pip install -U pysnmp
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution 
Remove all .egg file related to plugin then install with pip it work for me